# I am getting error in importing reportlab error in python

Tags: import, pip, reportlab

I am trying to import reportlab. I intalled reportlab using `pip insatall reportlab` after I called `pip list` its shows `reportlab` is installed but I am getting this error.

```
Import "reportlab.lib.units" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

This is how I tried to import.

**Note:** I am developing my project in a python `venv`

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.lib import colors
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages')  # Replace with the actual path to your virtual environment's packages directory

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.lib import colors
```

Comment: "*`sys.path.append`*" Why? Why not activate the virtual env before running python?